# How to get the json path based on filter on the key?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonpath

I had a json and I have to select the author name from the json object which does not contain **available** as a key in it

```
{
"store": {
"book": [
    {
        "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
    },
    {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
        "available":false
    },
    {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Herman Melville",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "price": 8.99
    },
    {
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "price": 22.99
    }
],
"bicycle": {
    "color": "red",
    "price": 19.95
}
},
"expensive": 10
}
```

So If it is possible using jsonpath or not is yes how can I achive that?

Comment: Are you trying to get books that are not having available key in it?

Comment: @VenkatLokeswar I am trying to get Author name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the JSONpath which can do the task for you so you can try this.

```
$..book[?(!@.available)].author
```

try it on
https://jsonpath.com/ it works the same way you want

Answer (score 4):

You could filter the book that does not have property `'available'` and then map through that filtered to get the author name

```js
const books = [
  {
    category: 'reference',
    author: 'Nigel Rees',
    title: 'Sayings of the Century',
    price: 8.95
  },
  {
    category: 'fiction',
    author: 'Evelyn Waugh',
    title: 'Sword of Honour',
    price: 12.99,
    available: false
  },
  {
    category: 'fiction',
    author: 'Herman Melville',
    title: 'Moby Dick',
    isbn: '0-553-21311-3',
    price: 8.99
  },
  {
    category: 'fiction',
    author: 'J. R. R. Tolkien',
    title: 'The Lord of the Rings',
    isbn: '0-395-19395-8',
    price: 22.99
  }
]

const authorNames = books
  .filter(book => !book.hasOwnProperty('available'))
  .map(book => book.author)

console.log(authorNames)
```

---

#### Reference

[Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the for..in construct to iterate through arbitrary properties of your object:

```
for (var key in obj.d) {
console.log("Key: " + key);
console.log("Value: " + obj.d[key]);}
```

Or check your available key like this, example

```
            var Data_Array = {
"Private": {
    "Price": {
        "Adult": "18",
        "Child": [{
            "FromAge": "0",
            "ToAge": "12",
            "Price": "10"
        }]
    }
}};var child = 'Child' in Data_Array.Private.Price && Data_Array.Private.Price.Child[0] || 'there is no child';console.log(child);
```

This will tell you whether available key is there or not, then get the author name like this, an example

By using word "b", You are still using key name.

```
    var info = {"fname": "A","lname": "B","Age": "34","favcolor": {"color1":"Gray", "color2":"Black", "color3":"Blue"}};
```

Look at the below snippet.

```
for(key in info) {var infoJSON = info[key];console.log(infoJSON);}
```